# Ways to help a math PhD out of depression

Tags: career

I have a friend who is having trouble in his math PhD career and is recently down with depression. He has decided to take a break from research and receive some medication. To help him recover faster and better, I am asking if anyone here with experience in helping depressed math PhDs could contribute his/her advice. Thanks in advance.

PS. If this question is more suitable on another stackexchange website, please feel free to move it there.

Comment: I believe Academia or Psychology might be more appropriate. If this person is not too depressed, they can search the web for others' experiences.   I think you should repost the question elsewhere, not here.  Gerhard "Out-of-scope Questions Can Be Depressing" Paseman, 2019.02.21.

Comment: I agree with Gerhard that this question is a bit out of place here and may fit in better on academia stackexchange (see here for example https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28257/overcoming-depression-and-getting-back-on-rails-with-phd-work), but I’d like to express sympathy for their situation and my well wishes; the life of any PhD student (but arguably pure math PhD’s more than most) can certainly be lonely at times, and I think we all understand the struggle to some extent.

Comment: By only looking at the attention received by this question, I think it absolutely belongs here.

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks. I will definitely pass your wishes to him.

Comment: @FanZheng, there is a clinic in New York that treats people with severe depression using ketamine. Here's the link: https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/the-fog-is-gone-how-ketamine-could-help-lift-hard-to-treat-depression-1.3784490

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do have something to share. I would ask the following:

1) Is he getting well with his advisor?

2) Does he have a daily routine (i.e wake up at 8AM everyday, preparing for teaching, going to gym at 11AM, reading papers from 1PM, attending weekly seminar at 3PM, etc). This can be *crucial* to get someone out of the state of depression.

3) Does he have potential plans after the PhD (with or without the degree)?

If the answers are No, I would suggest taking some concrete steps now (switch to a new advisor, form a daily life routine, consider a [Plan $B$](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/53f512c0e4b0a95765d3908f/t/5bbd7c89c8302522e6a9572e/1539144842079/Math_Pos_2019.pdf) or even [Plan $Z$](https://nianticlabs.com/jobs/data-scientist/) in case academia does not work for him).

In case he still loves doing research, I would encourage him/her talk to some mathematican in industry [but still actively doing research](http://simonrs.com/) to have a better sense how to achieve this. If I recall correctly, Yakov Eliashberg, Vladmir Berkovich and 
Jeffrey Lagarias all worked at industry at some point, not to mention street names like Yitang Zhang.

Comment: I personally like point 2. It can be given as a general advice which has nothing to do with depression or anything... I will save this :)

Comment: @Fan Zheng: Just hope your friend is okay...

Comment: @Bombyxmori I will definitely pass your regards to him.

Comment: @FanZheng: I contacted Simon and he said it is okay to put his website in the link. I was worried it might have put him in the spotlight. Now I am relieved.